# stack flex items to bottom of flex container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox

I am trying to align/stack 3 items to the bottom of a `display:flex` div. The only way I could manage it is by adding a 4th div on top & use javascript/jquery to adjust its height dynamically essentially to push those 3 items to the bottom.

Is there a pure CSS3 way to do this without resorting to javascript/jquery? Thanks

Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rockhammer/hw6tbgsd/). The 3 divs I want aligned/stacked to the bottom are `.searchForm`, `.tweetForm` and `.myMsg`. I'm currently resorting to putting a `.fudgeBox` on top to push them down to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this:

```
.searchForm { margin-top: auto; }
```

You can scrap the spacer div and all the JS.

An alternative would be `justify-content: flex-end` on the flex container (`.sideRight`).

- [`auto` margins demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hw6tbgsd/4/)
- [`justify-content` demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hw6tbgsd/5/)

Learn more about `justify-content` and `auto` margins here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Comment: Thanks, Michael. This is elegant. Works like magic! Alas my jsfiddle didn't quite represent my true code which also uses bootstrap 4. My real .sideRight also has the class col-md-4 which seems to prevent .sideRight from taking on height:100% and limits height of .sideRight to the sum of the elements within .sideRght. This seems to be preventing .searchForm { margin-top: auto; } from working. So I still need jquery to adjust height dynamically only I switched to adjusting margin-top of .searchForm instead of using a fudge div

Comment: Yeah, bootstrap and flexbox don't always play nice. You can sometimes override bootstrap by applying `!important` to your CSS, but it's hit and miss. Good luck :-)

Comment: I figured out why .searchForm { margin-top: auto; } was not taking effect. The bootstrap sticky footer template uses min-height:100% instead of height:100%. Reading the definitions, these two should give the same effect but they don't. By replacing min-height with height, { margin-top: auto; } works.

Answer (score 1):

In your .sideRight css use `justify-content` instead of `align-items`. When you use `flex-direction: column` the flow direction changes to vertical so the usage of `justify-...` and `align-...` basically switch.

Comment: Thanks, Tyler, for the quick response